# Inflate and menu.xml don't work as expected

Tags: java, kotlin, android-studio, mobile, android-inflate

[this is my java file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va42z.png)I follow to write this code  with a android development course online, but don't know why it doesn't work.

[[this is my menu.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwrvT.png),  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyC8G.png)]

Can anyone help me why is happening with my code?
I also have search a lot online, but don't find a helpful answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.